# The image on my slideshow won't show up

Tags: css, html, slideshow

- My images wouldn't show up on my slideshow.
- I have straight forward copied and paste the slide-show code for html and css from w3school and it worked for my previous porject but it is not working for my current project. I don't think, I did anything wrong in my html because before I code my css, images are there. Also if I delete code **display: none** the images appear again but it's all over the place.

  *please help this poor student to submit his assignment in tmr!*

Here are my codings for html5 and css

```
    .slide {
    width: 30%;
    margin: auto;

}



 .mySlides {
    display: none;
}



  .prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}


.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: #ec7979;
}



.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}



.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}



.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}



.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}


<section id="screens" class="odd">

            <h1 id="clear">App Screens</h1>

            <div class="slide">
                <!-- Slideshow container -->
                <div class="slideshow-container">

                    <!-- Full-width images with number and caption text -->
                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
                        <img src="img/store.png" style="width:100%">
                        <div class="text">store page</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
                        <img src="img/home.png" style="width:100%">
                        <div class="text">home page</div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mySlides fade">
                        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
                        <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
                        <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
                    </div>

                    <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
                    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
                    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
                </div>
                <br>

                <!-- The dots/circles -->
                <div style="text-align:center">
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
                    <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <p>'My wedding' is an online platform where people share<br> ideas and experiences about their wedding.</p>

        </section>
```

[before deleting display none](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckstP.png)
[after deleting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhe4u.png)

Comment: Did you include the js part? It's important. Without, they won't show up.
The js removes the display none from the current image.

Comment: yes i just realised that was the problem thank u so so much!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you share w3 school slider link where you got code for slider.


<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Did you used script in your code? Check my updated Answer